# Cannot deserialize Json object to dictionary

Tags: c#, jquery, json, serialization

I have a JSON object create in my jquery file as

```
{"showmiddleinitial":"True","showprefix":"True","showsuffix":"True"}
```

now I m sending this object to my controller using AJAX call by parsing it

```
$.parseJSON({"showmiddleinitial":"True","showprefix":"True","showsuffix":"True"})
```

or

```
{"showmiddleinitial":"True","showprefix":"True","showsuffix":"True"}
```

for both the above mentioned scenarios I m getting followign errors

```
Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]]'.
```

or

```
Error converting value "{"showmiddleinitial":"True","showprefix":"True","showsuffix":"True"}" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]]'.
```

Can any one lead me in the right direction?
I m using ASP.net with C#, MVC and Jquery

I can not do much in my C# code since that is static and hence I have to rely on jquery only.
the object in c# is of type

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> attributesList
```

Well... I got to the bottom of issue and noted that sending

```
$.parseJSON([{"showmiddleinitial":"True","showprefix":"True","showsuffix":"True"}])
```

resolves the issue.
Can any one please let me know how to add square braces to JSON object from jquery, ofcourse without adding them manualy

Comment: try `JSON.stringify(param)`..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058656/cannot-deserialize-json-object-into-type-system-collections-generic-list

Answer (score 0):

Your json string values should be wrapped by quotes like

```
string json = @"{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":""value2""}";
```

then call

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

Comment: i think square braces were required [{"showmiddleinitial":"True","showprefix":"True","showsuffix":"True"}], resolved teh purpose